# Unity3d Pixel Art Artifacts

Tags: unity3d

Я занимаюсь разработкой игры на Unity в стиле Pixel Art, и у появилась меня проблема: прозрачные полосы на краях спрайтов.
[image: Проблема]
Как мне это устранить?
Sprite фильтр: Point
Сглаживание и анизотропная фильтрация отключены.

Comment: Словесно проблему можно описать?  И перевести бы вопрос на язык форума.

Comment: Прошу прощения, добавил, перевел)

Comment: http://www.unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=13702